# Add a gap in chartjs line chart

Tags: chartjs-2.6.0

Having a standard line chart like this one
[Connected dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CDc6.png)

Is it possible to add a gap between two dots on the same series?
I mean, not adding a new value to the series with no data

Like in the yellow highlighted part of following chart
[Disconnected dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04GsA.png)

To do that like in the orange part is easy, just add "null" data, but it's not what I need.

Thanks.